# Merging rows in SQL

Tags: php, sql, pervasive

My table looks like this:

```
Dept          Wk1          Wk2
100           25           50
200           25           50
300           25           50
400           25           50
500           25           50
```

My results need to look like this:

```
Dept          Wk1          Wk2
100           25           50
200           25           50
300           25           50
400           50           100
```

Things worth noting; the database is Pervasive PSQL10 and I'm using PHP to handle the results. I thought about doing this merge in PHP, but ideally if it could be done in the query that would save me the need for the extra code.

Reason for combining rows is that 2 depts will be treated as one when the data is pulled.

I think I'm overthinking it, but I've explored union, group by, and stuff (which I'm probably using incorrectly) and nothing is giving me what I need.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, because what I've read so far addresses rows that have the same values, but not different.

Here is what my query actually looks like:

```
SELECT
dept_workcenter,
SUM(case when right(date_sequence,2) between 0 and 7 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk1,
SUM(case when right(date_sequence,2) between 8 and 14 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk2,
SUM(case when right(date_sequence,2) between 15 and 21 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk3,
SUM(case when right(date_sequence,2) between 22 and 28 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk4,
SUM(case when right(date_sequence,2) between 29 and 31 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk5
FROM job_detail
WHERE job between '017079' AND '017207'
AND date_sequence BETWEEN '141200' and '141231'
AND dept_workcenter != ''
GROUP BY dept_workcenter
HAVING SUM(hours_worked) <> '0'
AND SUM(hours_worked) > '0.05';
```

Comment: Just update the one you're keeping, then delete the extra row.

Comment: What's the condition for the merge?

Comment: Adding/removing rows is not an option. I'm only allowed to look at the results. @DaaaahWhoosh

Comment: There isn't a condition other than I know exactly what departments need to be merged. @matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement in the `group by`:

```
select (case when dept in (400, 500) then 400 else dept end) as dept,
       sum(wk1) as wk1, sum(wk2) as wk2
from table t
group by (case when dept in (400, 500) then 400 else dept end)
order by dept;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, so thank you. Will apply this knowledge to future queries.

Comment: Just wanted to add, that the case statement in the group by didn't have any affect on my results, but the case in the select gave me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So basically take the `500` and merge it with the `400`?

```
SELECT Dept, SUM(Wk1) AS Wk1, SUM(Wk2) AS Wk2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Dept IN (400,500), Dept
```

Comment: I was thinking the answer would be something simple like this, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with my query.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an uncommon problem in reporting.  The typical method to handle this is to generate a temporary table in which you can modify the 500 to be 400, and then do a `GROUP BY` and `SUM`.  This method will become more useful the more complicated your reporting becomes over time.

```
create table #DeptReptTable from select * from department;

update #DeptReptTable set Dept = 400 where Dept = 500;

select Dept, SUM(Wk1) Wk1, SUM(Wk2) Wk2 from #DeptReptTable group by Dept

drop table #DeptReptTable
```

Note: The `#` in front of the temp table is a Sybase-ism, which will create a table tied to the current SQL connection / session.  I don't know if that magic works for Pervasive.

Comment: I will keep this in mind for future reference when I start dealing with much more complicated results, but thank you for your input.